# Nestjs update is returning null for other fields thereby giving validation issues

Tags: javascript, typescript, postman, nestjs, typeorm

I am working on Nest.js CRUD. Every other component is working fine but the update throws a validation error when I try to update a field saying the other fields cannot be left empty. I tried to fix this from the service file but I am still getting the validation error. I tried my best to tweak it in different ways but nothing is happening. Below is what I have been able to come up with. I do not know what I am doing wrong.

**account.repository.ts**

```
async updateAccount(
    id: string,
    updateAccountDto: UpdateAccountDto
  ): Promise<UpdateAccountDto> {
    let { bankName, accountName, accountNumber } = updateAccountDto;
    const account = this.findOneOrFail(id);
    const oldBankName = (await account).bankName;
    const oldAccountName = (await account).accountNumber;
    const oldAccountNumber = (await account).accountNumber;
    if (bankName === null) {
      bankName = oldBankName;
    }
    if (accountName === null) {
      accountName = oldAccountName;
    }
    if (accountNumber === null) {
      accountNumber = oldAccountNumber;
    }
    const query = this.createQueryBuilder('account');
    await query
      .update(Account)
      .set({ bankName, accountName, accountNumber })
      .where('account.id = :id', { id })
      .execute();
    return updateAccountDto;
  }
```

**account.controller.ts**

```
@Put('/update/:id/')
  updateAccount(@Param('id') id: string, @Body() uaDto: UADto) {
    return this.accountService.updateAccount(id, uaDto);
  }
```

**account.service.ts**

```
async updateAccount(id: string, updateAccountDto: UpdateAccountDto) {
    return this.accountRepository.updateAccount(id, updateAccountDto);
  }
```

**account.dto**

```
export class CreateAccountDto {
  @IsNotEmpty()
  accountName: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  accountNumber: string;

  @IsNotEmpty()
  bankName: string;
}
```

**account.entity,ts**

```
@Entity()
export class Account {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  accountName: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  accountNumber: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  bankName: string;
}
```

Comment: Can you share the validation error?

Comment: It just just picks the name of the field and add cannot be empty. For example ***bankName cannot be empty***

Comment: But this error is coming from validators or an internal error from query.